# VBA - Protection and Worksheet_calculate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function, protected

I am trying to change the color of a cell based on the value that it gets through the formula applied to it. I also want to keep the sheet Protected. I have some unlocked cells, which I use to put manual values thus subsequently changing the color of the "Q13" cell

this is how my code looks like, I am a novice to VBA, what am i doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveSheet.Protect Password = "coi2020", UserInterfaceOnly = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()

If ActiveSheet.Range("Q13") < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Caution, Budget out of limit"
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
If ActiveSheet.Range("Q13") >= 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q13").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting on Q13 would be an easy solution, no vba code needed for this.

If you prefer macro, add an ActiveSheet.Unprotect ... line before formatting then protect again with Activesheet.Protect ... You can use "else" in the if ... then statement, your code can be simpler.